# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType - Angular 9

Tags: angular, build, aot

I'm running into bugs after bugs and fixes after fixes, until this one that i don't seem to understand. The app gets compiled but home page is empty and the error: `core.js:36236 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType`

The Data Service

```
@Injectable({ -> some say it isnt needed but i ran into other issue...
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(@Inject(String) private url: string, private http: HttpClient){}



  public getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
  }


}
```

The call in the home component (avoind forkjoin, keeping it simple for now)

```
 categories: any[];
  products: any[]=[];
  filteredProducts: any[]=[];
  category: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {
    this.dataService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
      this.categories=data[0]['categories'];
      console.log(this.categories)
    })
    this.dataService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
      this.products=data[0]['products'];
      console.log(this.products)
    })
```

The categoriesService (products is the same)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoriesService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) { 
    super('assets/categories.json', http)
  }
}
```

Also I have `"aot": false,` in the Angular.JSON

EDIT2: the app. module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { CategoriesService } from './services/categories.service';
import { ProductsService } from './services/products.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

  ],
  providers: [HttpClient, DataService, CategoriesService, ProductsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

An the updated error :)

```
Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[DataService -> String -> String -> String]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
```

EDIT 3 : Now I have a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6ure2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts) , but with no parent Service or class inheritance like I wanted. The code also belongs to `@Michael D`

Comment: Might be an Ivy related issue. Try to disable it in tsconfig.json file: `"enableIvy": false`. For more info see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31314

Comment: Do you have provider for `String` token/type?

Comment: @Michael D, nice to meet again :)  I cant find this setting...

Comment: I wiil edit and show more code

Comment: `@Inject(String) private url: string` this code means that for creating instance of DataService you need value of `String` provider. Without this provider you could not create instance of the service.

Comment: Try to remove @Inject(String)

Comment: can you make that as an aswer, please? it's in the app module right?

Comment: @izmaylovdev, I removed but the error remains

Comment: @Mellville: In that case, you could ignore the Ivy aspect of the issue.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @ Aakash Garg , I think so

Comment: @Aakash Garg  here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6ure2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Thought it has no inheritance or service extension. But its working

Answer (score 0):

You have modules in `providers` array it is not place for modules (use `imports`).

Same for services inside of `imports` array (imports array for modules only), it's the reason of provided error.

Also:

`@Inject(String) private url: string`

This code means that for creating instance of DataService you need value from DI by `String` token/type. Without this provider you could not create instance of the service.

Comment: No, it didnt work and its strange because ive worked both ways without ptoblems. I removed the sing Injector, updated the providers array in app.module `providers: [HttpClient,HttpClientModule, DataService, CategoriesService, ProductsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})`, but the error persists